Is CI/CD a myth
Perhaps because I'm primarily a coder, I don't understand the benefit of CI/CD, or any related terms such as scrum, agile, etc.

In my opinion, testing can be done locally on development computer;
testing cannot replace manual code review, a lot of security features are not easily tested using automated scripts, there are lots of code paths whose functional correctness need to be examined, not to mention the many possible edge cases (speaking as a full-stack developer looking at back-end codes) (small addition) - these needs human review in addition to testing (in some case, test cases also need reviews). The essence of this point is to express my doubt on any exaggeration of benefit offered by CI/CD over security;
the whole concept of CI/CD seem to be advertised towards managers and other non-coders, and generally for projects that aren't security-critical.

I've seen claims of benefit of CI/CD such as "faster xxx", "less bugs", "better code quality", etc. but except "faster xxx" (which I don't see why it's true), all other quality dimensions can be achieved though other means - style guide, use of linters, mentoring, etc.
So with all those said, what's the true benefit, application and non-applications of CI/CD?

In a security critical environment, consider how important the ability to roll out patches for vulnerabilities fast is? And then consider, why can't you be that fast for all your releases, so you are practiced and confident when you do need to handle vulnerabilities.

@user1937198, ticking-timebomb scenarios more often influence people's minds in ways that lead to inferior behaviour overall. Not least here because it presents timebombs as an occasional fact of professional life where developers are expected to step in and heroically defuse. It does this when the setting of a ticking timebomb would usually be the result of their own criminal incompetence in the first place, and the most likely outcome is unforeseen detonation.

"testing can be done locally on development computer" Sure. If you are the only developer working on a project. And your project is a calculator. And not a sophisticated one.

What security features are not easily testable?

@ThomasOwens 0-days?

@DannyNiu That isn't a security feature. A zero day is a vulnerability that has been found (and sometimes exploited) that doesn't have a patch. I can't think of any security features or controls that wouldn't be easily testable.

0-days are never found in CI/CD or any kind of testing. The essence of my second point is to express my doubt on any exaggeration of benefit offered by CI/CD over security.

@DannyNiu This gives me enough information to give an answer.

0-days are never found CI/CD because what gets found in CI/CD never gets released and never becomes a 0-day. The 0-days are the bugs you find when they make the news.

What do you mean when you say "CI/CD"? How do you think it's related to Scrum? Why do you think it can't be used together with code review (etc.)?

@JacobisonCodidact I was browsing through software project management methodologies, and these terms came up feeling alienating. CD/CI happens to be the #1 I want to grasp.


In my opinion, testing can be done locally on development computer;

Of course it can. And it should be done. CI/CD is not "instead" of it, but rather "in addition" to it.

testing cannot replace manual code review

Testing and code review are two separate things. The main purpose of testing is to prevent regression.
The problem with code review is that the bigger the app is, the harder it is to spot mistakes. The piece of code you modify may affect something in a different part of app, that noone sees. This happens to me (and people around me) all the time. Humans are just very limited.

a lot of security features are not easily tested using automated scripts

Security is inherently hard to test, that's correct. But that doesn't mean that other things (features) are. It is not really the point of CI/CD to test security. Unless the project you are working on is actually about security. Vast majority of projects are not.

there are lots of code paths whose functional correctness need to be examined, not to mention the many possible edge cases

Indeed. And that's precisely where the tests are needed. Also, I'm not sure how is that related to CI/CD? You could literally say the same about any form of testing. So are you saying that automatic testing is not needed? Regardless of CI/CD? That's just plain wrong.

So with all those said, what's the true benefit, application and non-applications of CI/CD?

To understand that we need to establish a fundamental rule. And that is: do not trust developers. You may think that you are a coding god, and hey, you might actually be. Except that coding gods don't exist and everyone makes mistakes. And developers are lazy. I am lazy. And yes, I am a coding god. ;) Do you want to know how many times I pushed code to main branch without running tests locally? A lot. I'm sorry, that's the truth: you cannot trust developers. And that's why you need mandatory CI/CD platform, which will always run tests, regardless of developers' laziness.

I would add to that fundamental rule that you definitely do not want to trust developers' local environments when building and testing your application - testing on a separate machine means that you'll catch the "I thought everyone had this environment variable included, and so didn't realize we didn't include our dependency for this one thing." issues. You're forcing your developers to document their build process so that their machine could get wiped or break down, and you can still confidently build on another machine, and know that it will work there.


In my opinion, testing can be done locally on development computer

In a minority of cases, it could be. Mobile apps can only be tested in emulators. Embedded apps can only be tested in emulators. Large and distributed apps can usually not be tested on a single dev machine.
Even in those cases, having a computer run the tests on the code actually shipping to prod is far more reliable than a human testing code that might be going to prod.

testing cannot replace manual code review

And manual code review cannot replace testing.

there are lots of code paths whose functional correctness need to be examined, not to mention the many possible edge cases

All the more reason to have a computer do it.

So with all those said, what's the true benefit, application and non-applications of CI/CD?

Making software development faster, less risky, better code quality…
CI/CD means that you can release today rather than waiting for your weekly/monthly/quarterly release. Which means that you can try stuff out. If it’s not quite right or the customer doesn’t like it, you can just change it tomorrow.
It also means that you can make changes more confidently. The test suite will let you know if you caused any regressions. That means that people new or unfamiliar with the codebase can work effectively in it more quickly, since the suite will cover the biggest risks rather than their own familiarity with the code.
Honestly, quick and painless build/deploy pipelines are one of the few things that I’ve actually seen help every software development team.

Sounds plausible, for apps with commercial requirement on it. What about stuff that require thoughtful engineering? Such as a programming language or a library? For these I see more argument for a slow and more careful release cycle.

@DannyNiu - nope. The compiler I worked on did about 6 (unstable) releases a day. If anything, backwards compatibility needs made CI even more valuable. We versioned it less frequently though.

So we basically separate production releases from nightlies. I got it.

@DannyNiu Given that stability is critical for such things, CI/CD is vitally important for them too. Personally I would be less trusting of tools which weren't protected by a comprehensive suite of automated tests -- primarily as I would feel less confident about the developers allowing bugs to creep in to future updates (Bugs appearing in dependencies are often costly and disruptive).  The nature of such tools should also make them the ideal candidates for automated testing, given that they would (hopefully) have been engineered against very clear, detailed and precise API specifications.

@DannyNiu - if you’re only building nightly, your feedback loops are painfully slow.


In my opinion, testing can be done locally on development computer

With more powerful workstations and advancements in virtualization and containerization technology, more testing can be done locally on a development computer. However, there is still plenty of testing that can't be done in this type of environment.
Regarding technical testing, performance and load testing come to mind as something that can't be done locally for many applications. Although local testing and simulation may highlight potential performance bottlenecks, testing at the scale of production systems often needs to be done in dedicated environments.
Usability and user acceptance testing are also difficult in a local development computer. Again, some testing, especially usability testing, could be done locally or using tools that scan against usability standards. However, making the software available on the devices where end users interact can make usability and user acceptance testing more robust.
These types of testing aren't generally done within a CI/CD pipeline. However, a CI/CD pipeline can make it easier to carry out these tests by executing various levels of automated tests and, when those tests pass, packaging and deploying the software to environments where performance and load testing can be done. The build servers used to execute CI/CD pipelines can also be used to manage any automated performance and load testing.

testing cannot replace manual code review, a lot of security features are not easily tested using automated scripts, there are lots of code paths whose functional correctness need to be examined, not to mention the many possible edge cases (speaking as a full-stack developer looking at back-end codes) (small addition) - these needs human review in addition to testing (in some case, test cases also need reviews). The essence of this point is to express my doubt on any exaggeration of benefit offered by CI/CD over security;

Testing and code review serve very different purposes. Previously, I've written about the purpose of a code review. Although some organizations do use code reviews to find errors and defects, I don't think this is something that humans should be spending their time on. Developing a shared understanding of the system, cross-training, and ensuring the readability and maintainability of the code are far better focuses for the time people invest in code reviews.
It is possible to inject security testing into code reviews. If you have a CI/CD build pipeline, you can and should integrate linters and static analysis tools into the pipeline and expose those results to code reviewers. When humans are carrying out code reviews, they can review the results of these static analysis tools and flag any high priority items for resolution as part of the review process.
I also think it's a mistake to believe that security features can't be easily tested. Many of the items on the Common Weakness Enumeration (CWE) can indeed be found by testing. Others can be found by static analysis. Both testing and static analysis can be incorporated into a CI/CD pipeline. Similar to testing, a CI/CD pipeline can also make it easier to integrate dynamic analysis into a development process by making it easier to build, package, and deploy software to an environment where dynamic scanning tools can be used.

the whole concept of CI/CD seem to be advertised towards managers and other non-coders, and generally for projects that aren't security-critical.

I don't agree with this at all. The foundational work on CI/CD, whether it's the work from Kent Beck's Extreme Progamming (book) or Dave Farley's Continuous Delivery (YouTube, book) or Paul Duvall's Continuous Integration (book) are geared toward practitioners. Dave Farley has also talked about the application of CI/CD on critical projects, such as his past work in the highly regulated finance space.
This isn't to say that it's not important to sell it to managers. It is. The investment needed to set up and maintain a robust CI/CD pipeline is not trivial, and there is plenty of business value. However, there are also huge implications for developers when it comes to rapid feedback and a great confidence in the ability to build and deploy working software quickly and efficiently.

So with all those said, what's the true benefit, application and non-applications of CI/CD?

A few examples:

Rapid feedback. A CI/CD pipeline is built on fast feedback through automated tests. Having a controlled pipeline that integrates these automated checks with other types of checks and gives developers feedback regarding potential issues on the order of minutes is invaluable.
Confidence in build and deployment. CI/CD pipelines are controlled and automated. Any configuration and scripts used are managed and controlled carefully to ensure that each pipeline run is correct. The automation ensures that it happens the same way each time, regardless of the developers doing the work that causes the pipeline to be executed.
A foundation for longer-running tests. Although rapid feedback is key, not all testing and checks can be done quickly. The ability to automate deployment and run these longer-running tests more frequently reduces the overall feedback loops, giving the developers the information they need to make informed decisions about their work.


Looks like my other confusion is stemming from benefits of CI/CD are not always quantifiable. I'll digest.


Perhaps because I'm primarily a coder, I don't understand the benefit of CI/CD, or any related terms such as scrum, agile, etc.

Yes, almost everything in software today is old and familiar ideas dressed up in new fancy jargon. If they were spoken about more plainly and historical experience was consulted, then their advantages and absurdities would often be clearer.

In my opinion, testing can be done locally on development computer;

Perhaps for certain kinds of tests. However, complicated multi-user systems tend to acquire properties that make them difficult to test completely except in normal use, and many systems have automatic test suites that are far too heavy to be executed locally on the developer's own machine without impeding the progress of the developer.

testing cannot replace manual code review

Yes, automated tests do not replace the analysis work of all kinds that programmers perform. Effective suites of automated tests typically result from manual analysis, and automate certain routine testing activities that the analysis shows would be desirable to do and would otherwise have to be performed by hand or go undone.

a lot of security features are not easily tested using automated scripts

Adequate "testability" is a property of machinery that is typically regarded as desirable, and results from design and engineering that is good and skillful.

So with all those said, what's the true benefit, application and non-applications of CI/CD?

I think one basic principle of CI/CD is that deploying software is a repetitive routine activity, and therefore it should be a click-button exercise to control, as opposed to something that needs complicated attention and lots of human labour like getting a steam roller into gear. So if you want to release every 5 minutes, it should be possible.
I think another principle is that it's a reaction to a fixed release cadence, and says that the default release time should be immediately when the development work is done (or else with no more delay than is justified for the situation), rather than everything being either rushed or accumulated for fixed release dates.
As usual though, managing software development itself requires professional expertise and judgment, and staff who are engaged with the problems and constraints of their particular environment. What's appropriate for a one-man, in-house development function, is not necessarily appropriate for Google and Microsoft.

It sounds like you've been presented with a narrow view of CI/CD that doesn't fully reflect its purpose.

In my opinion, testing can be done locally on development computer

CI/CD doesn’t discourage local testing; rather, it complements it with build-agent testing, which catches issues like bad merges more effectively.

Testing cannot replace manual code review, a lot of security features are not easily tested using automated scripts [..] these needs human review in addition to testing (in some case, test cases also need reviews)

CI/CD doesn’t replace manual reviews; it simply automates repetitive checks, reducing the burden on manual efforts.

there are lots of code paths whose functional correctness need to be examined, not to mention the many possible edge cases (speaking as a full-stack developer looking at back-end codes)

Automated testing focuses developers on creating tests for these paths, saving time over repeated manual checks.

The essence of this point is to express my doubt on any exaggeration of benefit offered by CI/CD over security

Security remains critical; CI/CD helps automate checks but doesn’t claim to replace in-depth security assessments.

The whole concept of CI/CD seem to be advertised towards managers and other non-coders

Management buy-in is essential because CI/CD implementation requires resources and cultural shifts (dev capacity as a startup cost, dev training, changes to release comm processes).
The reason this is advertised to managers is to get them to buy into it. The reasons you see little advertisement to developers is because most of them are already on board with a CI/CD shift as it directly benefits their work process.

and generally for projects that aren't security-critical.

For compliance-heavy or critical applications (e.g., NASA, medical equipment), CI/CD is often modified due to regulatory demands, not because it's inherently insecure.

In short, CI/CD enables frequent, smaller releases, reducing risk per release and simplifying troubleshooting. While initially it requires setup, automation minimizes ongoing manual effort, providing efficiency gains that are scalable across teams and repetitive releases.
Automating something costs more effort than doing it manually once. But if you have to do it 100 times, it's better to automate it once than it is to do it manually 100 times.

CI/CD is absolutely real. It exists, and it solves some real world problems very well, and it helps a bit with the things that most developers think CI/CD is there to fix.

In my opinion, testing can be done locally on development computer

Yes, it can. and when you are writing your code you should be stepping though it and verifying that the data and code flow are behaving as expected. I do not want you to be trying to do this in the CI/CD pipeline. In the CI/CD pipeline I want to run a large number of basic sanity checks from the unit tests that you have also already written.  This is a fail safe mechanism to prevent something that is totally broken from being deployed onto the production servers.

testing cannot replace manual code review, a lot of security features are not easily tested using automated scripts, there are lots of code paths whose functional correctness need to be examined, not to mention the many possible edge cases (speaking as a full-stack developer looking at back-end codes) (small addition) - these needs human review in addition to testing (in some case, test cases also need reviews). The essence of this point is to express my doubt on any exaggeration of benefit offered by CI/CD over security;

The manual code review is often the trigger for the CI/CD process to start. When several people have reviewed your feature branch, and authorised a pull request, the action of closing the pull request and adding these changes to the existing code base doesnt replace the CI/CD process, but acts as the trigger point for a deployment onto a pre-production environment.

the whole concept of CI/CD seem to be advertised towards managers and other non-coders, and generally for projects that aren't security-critical.

Its more a case of CI/CD is a process that is not part of the core developer workload. It falls into the camp of the work that other people do, when the developer has actually made the product.
Here is what I value about CI/CD

Consistent releases. Its been 15 years since the last time I worked on a project and could tell which of the developers fixed the last bug and updated production. Why? Because developers do forget to commit all of the code. They test it on their machine. It works. They Deploy it.  Then the next bug fix is handled by a team mate, who doesnt have that last fix on their laptop, so when they fix the next bug and deploy, it also undeploys the last bug fix. Thats really annoying.

Reliable releases. Having a scripted automated process that takes the current code, builds the application, installs it into the run time environment and then places that runtime environment onto the production servers and routes live traffic to the code happens smoothly, consistently and with predictably. Doing this by hand allows mis-clicks to occur, steps to be missed out, a server to be forgotten about. Never mind if you are operating at cloud scale and need to deploy to 200 servers.

Automated Rollback. As part of the deployment onto the live servers, the CI/CD process can only route 1% of the live traffic to the new deployment, keeping the remaining traffic on the existing code base.  If the new containers show either a higher error rate or higher latency, then we can automatically abort the deployment and trigger an investigation ticket to the platform team.


In reality, the benefit of the CI/CD pipeline is really for the quality assurance processes - verifying that what is being tested is really the same as the thing being deployed and for the operations team - making deployments predictable, automatic, and whenever possible, something that can be done on a live site during working hours.


So with all those said, what's the true benefit, application and non-applications of CI/CD?

Frequent releases.
Everything else is hype.
Frequent releases means fast feedback loops. Which is golden. The salesmen often don't understand that and will tell you it can make toast if it will get you to buy. But just because they are full of crap doesn't mean this isn't a good thing. I never want to go back to a shop that needs 6 months of testing before a release.

Could you edit your added paragraph to avoid rhetorics? Non-native English speakers (such as me) find it hard to comprehend.

@DannyNiu sure, but please explain what you're calling rhetoric. As a native English speaker I think the whole answer is rhetoric.

Particularly: "and will tell you it can make toast if it will get you to buy", and "I never want to go back to a shop that needs 6 months of testing before a release".

@DannyNiu why are those "rhetoric" any more than "fast feedback loops"? I'd love to make it better. But first I need to understand what's wrong.

Maybe "rhetoric" isn't the best word (I machine translated it into English), it's more like idioms and slangs. I think vocabularies for standards (such as ISO IETF publictions) are more suitable.

@candied_orange, "I never want to go back to a shop that needs 6 months of testing before a release." - am I right that what you mean by this, is that with small changes constantly drip-fed to release under CI/CD, you avoid the lead time where changes are accumulated followed by the perceived need for extensive pre-release testing of all these changes together (unlike with a release of a large batch of changes, where the alternative to such thorough testing would be a sudden blitz of faults)?

@Steve yes Steve.

@DannyNiu what ISO IETF vocabularies? If you don't point me at it then all I can do is search. Google found Terminology Used in Internationalization in the IETF which helps with their stuff not mine. I dug up Electropedia: The World's Online Electrotechnical Vocabulary which is more general but they missed my entire field. Nothing about software or its development in here.

@candied_orange From my experience participating on POSIX mailing list, we don't put overly casual language or slangs into international standards. Your added paragraph has 2 which I've indicated in a previous comment. I would appreciate if you can edit them into plain English statements. Since you're asking me for specifics, I assume you've little experience participating in one, so all I can say is: write formally. I checked my dictionary a bit further, I think it's 2 instances of metaphors without lingual background.

@DannyNiu the only metaphors I used were "golden" (see meaning 5) and "crap" (see meaning 1). But you didn't single those out. The toast thing is not a metaphor or an idiom. I meant it as is. Ask idiots, selling things they don't understand, if it will make toast and they will say yes; even when it's not a toaster. It's aggressive salesmanship. Our field is full of it. If those links help I can add them to the answer.

So who's the idiots in this case? The non-technical managers? Who's the salesman? Who are they selling to? These are quite confusing and feel as if secret lingos.

@DannyNiu The salesmen, trying to convince you that CI/CD will give you "faster xxx", "less bugs", "better code quality". No, it gives you the ability to have frequent releases and the tight feedback loops that come with that. If it gives you any more than that it's because you paid attention to the feedback. You don't get that other stuff for free. It's work.

This answer suffers a bit from oversimplification. Frequent releasing is CD, not CI/CD. Yes, it is true that by enforcing CD, it almost inevitably forces your hand to implement CI which entails a bunch of other improvements that simplify the release process, but at the same time these improvements also have benefits/justifications on their own that his not inherently tied to the release process. CI/CD refers to a larger concept than just CD. OP's concern is one of imprecise justification being given for the pro CI/CD guideline, and this answer is just repeating the same kind of imprecision.

@candied_orange: "No, it gives you the ability to have frequent releases" You're arguing that we can't address indirect benefits, which is an act of cherry-picking for the sake of being able to condense your answer. The question as to why one would choose to implement CI/CD is not restricted to merely an explicit need to have more frequent releases. Claiming so effectively suggests that any company that has been making do with a slower release schedule wouldn't need to consider CI/CD, indirect benefits be damned. That's just not how communication works, nor how good practice is established

@flater the most effective defense against that accusation that a car doesn’t solve every promised transportation need on it own is to explain that it’s not self driving and that you have to know how to drive it yourself. By all means, teach them to drive.

@candied_orange: A more apt analogy would be that you're giving a driving lesson where you aren't allowed to say that turning the steering wheel makes the car turn, you're only allowed to explain that it puts an angular force onto the steering axle. The subsequent effects of that should point themselves out on their own, right? I mean, just look at how the car was built. Do I need to explain everything here? Pedantic correctness of what is the most directly adjacent effect (and shutting everything else out) is not a productive attitude to communication, especially when teaching new concepts.

Many customers, especially large ones, do NOT want constant updates and releases because it bogs down their own acceptance and integration testing. We release a minor release every other week to customers, and a major release twice a year. We use CI/CD to prepare those releases for customers to download and install at their leisure, and more than a few are years behind in their updates despite frequent reminders they're loosing support after 2 year! Internally every approved PR is prepared for delivery to test systems automatically, and installed on all test systems every night.

ctd... Or at the push of a button an admin can install it on any system that needs it more quickly than that. That's how CI/CD works in reality in many organisations. It speeds up our internal operations without bothering the customers with frequent forced updates.
